# ACF form edit front end post title does not change permalink

Tags: custom-field, forms

I have create edit ACF form in front end and i wrote that post title can be edit also by that form.

but when I change post title field, my permalink does not change based on title.

```
<?php 
                if ( ( is_user_logged_in()  ) ) {
                    echo "<div class='acf-edit-post'>";
                    acf_form_head();
                        acf_form (array(
                            //'post_id'            => 401, // Get the post ID
                            'post_title'         => get_the_title(),
                            'field_groups'       => array(7), // Create post field group ID(s)
                            'form'               => true,
                            'return'             => '%post_url%',
                            'html_before_fields' => '',
                            'html_after_fields'  => '',
                            'submit_value'       => 'Save Changes',
                            'updated_message'    => __("Post updated", 'acf')
                        ));
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: use acf_form_head() before get_header();. For more reference check this link : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Comment: thank you but I have tried that, it still the same

Comment: turn wp_debug to true in wp-config.php and see if there's any error

Comment: i have try that also but does not print any thing error

Comment: whic template file is this code located in? The post_id has to be provided if its not inside the loop

Comment: this is store in single post template (singl-cpt.php) all the value fetch from current id are right but when i change post_title  does not automatically generate new slug for link. FYI post_title is not custom field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you found an answer to that yet? I recently needed to redirect users to a custom made page that hosts an ACF form and loads the values of that particular post into the form. You are going to need 2 things in order to make that work:

1. In your functions.php, redirect non-admin users to your edit page (which you'll create at step 2) in the frontend. To do that add:

   ```
   add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'custom_edit_post_link', 10, 1 );

   function custom_edit_post_link( $url ) {
       # If user is admin go to Dashboard
       if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
             return $url;
       }
       # else redirect the user to my edit entry page & send the post_id on URL
       return esc_url( add_query_arg( 'post_id', get_the_ID(), home_url('/entry-edit/') ) ); //where entry-edit is my page's slug
   }
   ```

https://github.com/Alina-chan/acf_ideas/blob/master/front-end%20post%20edit%20with%20acf%20form/functions.php

2. Now create a custom template for your page and name it {name}-edit.php. In there you should place your ACF form. Take a look at mine here: 
   https://github.com/Alina-chan/acf_ideas/blob/master/front-end%20post%20edit%20with%20acf%20form/post-edit.php

By getting the post_id from your URI, you can use it inside your template and load the post's values in your ACF form.

Hope it helped you a bit!